# Weird eval() in IE7

Tags: eval, javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code:

```
eval($(this).text());
```

Now `this.text()` contains about 50 lines of JS with `''`s and `""`'s and various JS code.

Now, FireFox, Safari and Chrome have no problem executing this code. However, IE7 reports:

> Error: Expected ')' Code: 0

Now, I assume this is some `""`,`''` or `()`, ie syntax problem... however, I can't reproduce this in smaller code base. Everything I try seems to works in IE7 and FF (& friends).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance,

Comment: I suppose "eval() is dangerous; don't use it" isn't that helpful as advice.  Question: if you pull the text out, put it in a javascript file as is, and run it in IE, does it give the same error?  Does it tell you anything useful (like, say, a line number)?

Comment: This is a good idea. Make sure the problem isn't with eval, then start crawling your code. Sometimes I've had problems with nested JS comments in IE, check that out.

Comment: Hi, yep, if the code isn't executed via eval() it works fine... I'll strip comments and see if that helps now...

Comment: Nope, removing comments never worked. Shall i post the code being executed?

Comment: Sure, post the code if it's not too long.

Comment: Hello,

http://pastebin.com/ZWLJs2aR

OK, this is the code which not ran in an eval() works fine in IE7 and FF. Hope you can help, sorry if it looks confusing, it's generated from XSL.

Comment: @bobbyjoe, have you solved this? Your pastebin is no longer available, can you post your code again?

Comment: @Hnatt I was having similar problems (some minutes ago) and it seems to me that the IE7 parser gets unhappy on stuff like `eval("var x = { a: 0, b:3, }")` and I needed to remove the comma after `3` to make it work.  I'm totally guessing here.